# A simple question about p-groups (possibly infinite)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-groups

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $q$ be relatively prime to $p$.

Prove that if $G$ is a $p$-group and $g \in G$,then there exists $x \in G$ with $qx=g$.

---

My question:I was able to prove this when $G$ is finite,but how do we prove it when $G$ is infinite?Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to take $x$ to be a power (multiple) of $g$, which works either way; what was your argument in the finite case?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan When $G$ is finite,I defined $f:G \to G$ by taking each $x \in G$ to $qx$,and so $f$ is injective,hence bijective.

Comment: You can apply this argument to the subgroup generated by $g$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan You're right :)

Comment: Otherwse you can follow Qiaochu's initial idea which was to us Bezout's theorem

Comment: @Max Thanks for your comment!Honesty speaking,I am not familiar with the applications of Bezout's theorem,so it would be greatly helpful if you write an answer utilizing Bezout's theorem,alternatively,any hint would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say that $g$ is of order $p^n$. Then by Bezout's theorem, there are $u,v$ with $p^nu + qv = 1$

In particular, $g = (p^nu + qv)g = up^nv + q(vg) = q(vg)$. So $x=vg$ works.

Note that I used additive notation to fit your question, but this works just as well over nonabelian groups